# Error while using LAST() aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently I started working on a project. In which I want to fetch the last record inserted in the database.

Query is:

```
SELECT c.lat, c.lng, LAST(v.count) 
FROM camera_camera c , camera_cameravehiclecount v 
WHERE c.id = v.cameraid
```

I am using the `LAST()` aggregate function but I am getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(v.count) from camera_camera c , camera_cameravehiclecount v
>   WHERE c.id = v.came' at line 1

I cross checked the syntax from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp) but still I am getting this error. I am using DB4free as my online database.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to get the last inserted value of "count" from the table where id,s are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The w3 page suggests a workaround, since LAST isnt in mysql. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

You can try this to get the same thing:

```
SELECT c.lat, c.lng, v.count
FROM camera_camera c , camera_cameravehiclecount v 
WHERE c.id = v.cameraid 
ORDER BY v.count DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN`.

Second, you need a column to specify what last is.  Say it is the `id` on the vehicle count table.  Then you would use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT c.lat, c.lng, LAST(v.count) 
FROM camera_camera c JOIN
     camera_cameravehiclecount v 
     ON c.id = v.cameraid 
ORDER BY v.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  `ORDER BY v.count DESC` is not appropriate, unless you know that that column is only increasing.